# AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been suffering for 2 hours with the same error, I found out from a friend, I even tried chatgpt, nothing helped

```
# ID канала для отправки информации о платеже и участнике
payment_channel_id = 1148335023028707359

class DepositView(discord.ui.View):
  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

  @discord.ui.button(label='Пополнить!', custom_id='deposit_button', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
  async def deposit_button_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
      # Отправляем запрос в личные сообщения
      await interaction.user.send('Какую сумму вы хотите пополнить?')

      # Ждем ответа пользователя
      response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == interaction.user)

      try:
          amount = int(response.content)
          total_amount = calculate_total_amount(amount)
          # Отправляем итоговую сумму и реквизиты в личные сообщения
          await interaction.user.send(f'Итоговая сумма к оплате: {total_amount}\nРеквизиты:\n...')

          # Создаем уникальный ID запроса
          request_id = generate_request_id()

          # Отправляем информацию о платеже и участнике в специальный канал
          payment_channel = bot.get_channel(payment_channel_id)
          await payment_channel.send(f'Запрос на пополнение!\n- user_id: {interaction.user.id}\n'
                                     f'- user_balance_wait: {amount}\n- DATE: {current_date()}')

          # Сохраняем информацию о запросе в базе данных
          save_payment_request(request_id, interaction.user.id, amount)

          # Отправляем информацию о номере запроса в личные сообщения
          await interaction.user.send(f'Платеж на рассмотрение. Номер запроса: {request_id}\n'
                                      f'Ожидайте подтверждения от администрации.')
      except ValueError:
          await interaction.user.send('Пожалуйста, введите корректное число.')

# Вспомогательные функции
def calculate_total_amount(amount):
    # Логика расчета итоговой суммы с комиссией 1%
    return amount * 1.01

def generate_request_id():
    # Генерация уникального ID запроса при помощи рандома
    return random.randint(100000000, 999999999)

def save_payment_request(request_id, user_id, amount):
    # Логика сохранения информации о запросе в базе данных
    conn_requests = sqlite3.connect('ezshop_requests.db')
    cursor_requests = conn_requests.cursor()

    cursor_requests.execute('INSERT INTO requests (requests_id, requests_user_id, requests_user_balance_wait) '
                            'VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (request_id, user_id, amount))

    conn_requests.commit()
    conn_requests.close()

def current_date():
    # Логика получения текущей даты при помощи date
    return date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

@bot.command(name='deposit', hidden=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def deposit(ctx):
    # Создаем Embed
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Пополнение баланса', description='Нажмите кнопку для начала пополнения')
    # Добавляем тамбнейл, картинку, футер
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon.url)
    embed.set_image(url=ctx.guild.icon.url)
    embed.set_footer(text='Deposit v2')

    # Создаем View с кнопкой
    view = DepositView()

    # Отправляем сообщение с Embed и кнопкой в канал, откуда была вызвана команда
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, view=view)
```

discord.py

I wanted to make a manual deposit system, yeah, something floated there to create it, it was planned that the bot would write to the participant in private messages after pressing the Replenish button, ask for the amount of replenishment, then create a payment number in db and send it to the administrator for confirmation

Comment: Show us where the `deposit_button_callback()` function is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line: `async def deposit_button_callback(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):`

To this: `async def deposit_button_callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):`

In buttons the order matters.